# Process doesn't terminate

Tags: c#, excel

I'm using this code to create an Excel report:

```
 var excel = new Excel.Application();
 foreach (var report in m_reports)
     report.PrintReport(excel.Workbooks.Add().Sheets.Add());
 excel.Visible = true;
```

Everything works fine. However, when the user manually closes Excel, the Excel process remains open in the Task Manager. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on MSDN about [Releasing ComObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject.aspx)

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( excel );
```

also if you are wanting to do something else within that foreach loop I would suggest wrapping your code in the proper code block format for example

```
 foreach (var report in m_reports)
 {
    report.PrintReport(excel.Workbooks.Add().Sheets.Add());
 }
 excel.Visible = true;
 //Release the ComObject
 System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( excel );
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer has a good rule:
[How do I properly clean up Excel interop objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects/)

"Never use two dots with com objects."

You're declaring workbook and sheet objects without ever releasing them - thats why the process won't quit.

Comment: I thought that release of this objects will kill process and I need to keep Excel program oppened. Thank you, I'll try it a bit later.